# Writing subroutine to log file

Tags: perl

I want to write subroutine test to log file, for example:

```
my ($logfile, $logpath);
$logpath = '/usr/bin';
$logfile = "$logpath/log.txt"; 
open (LOG,">>","$logfile") || die ("Error : can't open log file");

sub test
{
   print "Hi\n"; 
   my $date = `date`;
}

sub logFunc
{
   print LOG "Writing log files\n";
   print LOG test(); # we cannot do like this :)
}

logFunc();
```

Say there are 15+ subroutines.  To write commands in each subroutine to log file, I have to write:

```
print LOG "[Command]\n";
```

which works fine, but script length is huge.  Using common subroutine, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe he/she is old-fashioned ;)

Comment: Because all the Perl tutorials have not been updated in a long, long, long time.

Comment: It's not clear from your example what you expect to print in `log.txt` after "Writing log files\n".  Do you want "Hi\n", the output of date(1), both, or what?

Comment: @pilcrow : Consider there are 15 subroutines each contains some shell commands. whenever any of the subroutine is executed commands inside it are written in log.txt, so to write those commands to log.txt currently I have wrtten print LOG "[Command]" in each subroutine. so any their any way like I can create a separate subroutine for logs & whenever main subroutines are exectuted that will call log subroutine & that will write commands to log.txt, so that I can remove all print statements from every subroutine & reduce code length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1. Are you sure you have (and want) write-access to `/usr/bin/`?
2. You don't ever call your `log()` or your `test()` subroutines. No one will call any of them automatically.
3. The name `log` clashes with the built-in `log` function. So you will either have to call it with a prepended ampersand `&log()` which is ugly or rename it.
4. Your `test()` sub only has an implicit return value. Rather return the value of `$date` explicitly.
5. You are using the deprecated 2-argument version of `open` using a bare-word global file handle. Please use the 3-arg version with a lexical filehandle: `open my $log_fh, '>>', $logfile`.

Comment: Function names are taken as example, you can consider any name for that. What I want to achieve is instead of writing
print LOG "xyz"; everytime, can I directly write subroutine directly to log file.

Comment: Take my advice, apply it to your little script and what you want to achieve will just work.

Comment: (hint: 2) and 3) are the most relevant points here. But please don't ignore the others of you really want to learn Perl.)

Answer (score 4):

A few hints:

- Always add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script.
- Since you're dealing with reading and writing files, you should also add `use autodie;`. This will automatically kill your program if you cannot open a file, or you cannot write to an open file.
- Don't use OS commands when Perl probably can do exactly what you want without calling an OS command.
- A Subroutine usually takes arguments and returns a value of some sort. In your case, have your `test` subroutine return something to write to the log. Or, create just a log subroutine that writes to a log, and have your test subroutine call it.

Here I'm reversing your subroutine calls. I create a `write_to_log` subroutine to handle my subroutine calls. My `write_to_log` adds the date/time stamp and writes that and my message. My various subroutines now just call `write_to_log` for me.

Notice all of my subroutines return some sort of value. The `say` command (as well as `print`) returns a non-zero value on success and a `0` on failure. I can use this to test whether my call to my subroutine worked or not.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use features qw(say);   #Allows you to use `say` instead of `print:

my $log_file = "/usr/bin/log.txt";    #You have write permission to this directory?

open my $log_fh, ">", $log_file;

my test ( $log_fh ) or die qq(Can't write to the log);   #Pass the file handle to log
my test2 ( $log_fh ) or die qq(Can't write to the log);

close $log_fh;

sub test {
    return write_to_log ( $log_fh, "Hello World!" );
}
sub test2 {
    return write_to_log ( $log_fh, "Goodbye World!" );
}

sub write_to_log {
    my $file_handle  = shift;
    my $message      = shift;

    use Time::Piece;

    my $time = localtime->cdate;
    return say {$file_handle} "$time: $message";
}
```

Here's a [webpage](http://modernperl.net/books/evaluating-a-good-perl-book.html) that lists good books for learning *modern Perl* and what to look for in those books. If you're beginning to learn Perl, use one of these books.

Answer (score -1):

For those who can't use the modules and need a quick logging function because often we don't have the time, or access to install modules especially in legacy applications.

A simple function that uses basic perl commands only:

```
#Print based on loglevel 
sub log {
    #Loglevels hashmap - do not modify
    my %LOG_LEVELS=( "CRITICAL"=>-1, "ERROR"=>1, "WARNING" =>2 , "INFO"=> 3, "DEBUG"=> 4);
    #get current log level in the script and desired loglevel for this message
    my $desiredlevel=uc($_[0]);
    my $currentlevel=uc($loglevel);
    #If invalid level assume its a debug message
    if ($LOG_LEVELS{$desiredlevel}+0 == 0){
        $desiredlevel="DEBUG";
    }
    printf("[$desiredlevel] $_[1]\n") if $LOG_LEVELS{$currentlevel}+0 >= $LOG_LEVELS{$desiredlevel}+0;
}
```

And to use this function:

Set loglevel in this case I pass it a cmd arg

```
my $loglevel="INFO"; #default
#parse command-line vars 
    foreach $arg (@ARGV){
        chomp($arg);
        ($key,$val) = split(/=/,$arg,2);
        if ($key eq "url"){ $url = $val; }
        if ($key eq "loglevel"){ $loglevel = $val; }
    
    }
```

Then call the function with the level and message

```
&log("INFO", "Calling script to generate result");
$result=`blahblah`;
if (index($result,"OK") == -1) {
    &log("ERROR", "Generate role FAILED with status $result");
}
else
{
    &log("DEBUG", "Sucessfully created ".$result);
}
```

It doesn't handle every case but you can easily add more levels with higher/lower numbers in the LOG_LEVELS array.

More validation needs to be added but already handles different cases: INFO info inFO are all valid.